# iOS Xcode 10.2 fails to attach debugger to Apple Watch

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode10.2, watchos-5

I'm trying to debug my WatchKit app on a real device. I select the watchkit app target, and my real device + Apple watch as deployment target. Xcode succeeds deploying the app to device, but seems to quit before the debugger finishes attaching. I see the "finished running app on watch" in Xcode, then the watch screen times out and the debugger attachment finishes.

**How can I deploy and debug a WatchKit app on an actual watch?**

If I select Debug> Attach to process > select process on apple watch, it times out as well.

Do I have a defective device, or is this the general Xcode bug? Do I not have some flags set? I can see my device and it's paired watch in the list of devices in Xcode.